# Visual Studio 2010 crashes when opening a solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a problem with my Visual Studio 2010 ultimate ( Final Edition )
This problem occurs when I opening the any Solution even new project like Console App !
the windows Error Reporting show me this Error Key :

> EventType : clr20r3     P1 : devenv.exe     P2 : 10.0.30319.1     P3 : 4ba1fab3

please guide me, how i can fix this problem
I'm between rock and hard place
thank's a lot

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. What I've seen is that its probably just a file missing that Visual Studio needs to run.

Answer (score 0):

Though this is a rather old question still [this link](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/559814/visual-studio-2010-10-0-30319-1-rtmrel-net-framework-4-0-30319-rtmrel-crash-frequently) could be useful. Basically the suggested workaround is to turn off the "Use hardware graphics acceleration if available" option (in Tools->Options->Environment->General).